# adding a calculated column on QlikView

Tags: qlikview

I'm new on QV and trying to add a column to an existing table.
I want to add to the sales table a sales revenue column that is the sum of salesprice from products table * quantity from sales table.

All of this because I wish to have a list box of sales revenue.

Thanks in advance to all the helpers!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to in the unit price onto the Sales table and then do the calculation. You can't do sub-queries so it will have to be something of the following form;

```
Sales:
Load Product_No,
     Quantity
from Sales.xls;

left join
Load Product_No
     Unit_Price
from Products.xls;

Final_Sales:
load Product_No,
     Quantity,
     Unit_Price,
     Quantity*Unit_Price as Revenue
resident Sales;

drop table Sales;
```

The final drop table statement is very important otherwise you will get a massive synkey between the table that you do not want